# Faster way to avoid catching an exception

Tags: python, exception, comments

Is there a way to temporary stop catching some exception?

The point is that when you have more exceptions which are being catched in a code and you want to comment them because you want to see all the things printed when exception is raised (print exception is not sufficient), you have to comment try, except, code in except, finally, code in finally and change an indent of the code where the exception can be raised. This commenting is very time-consuming when you have to do it many times.

```
    #try:
    pel.check_one_destination()
    #except Exception as e:
        #pel.driver.save_screenshot('log.png')
        #print e
```

Comment: Please see if [`traceback.print_exc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc) does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `raise` keyword inside the except block and it will raise the caught exception back. Found it useful during testing.

Example -

```
try:
    #code that leads to exception
except Exception as e:
    #handle exception
    raise #for testing what the exception was, and etc.
```